# php-fpm user unable to run node commands

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, centos7, node.js, vagrant

- I have a vagrant instance running CentOS7.
- This vagrant instance is running Nginx to host websites locally on my mac.
- I have php-fpm running to support processing of php files.
- Finally, I have a php file that calls a node.js script.

What I am finding is that the user:group that php-fpm is configured under is unable to run node commands. I have node installed (via nvm) on the user I ssh into the box with, but the php-fpm user has no access to that installation.

Is there a way to install Node/Npm in a way that the php-fpm user-group can access?

Thank you

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#enterprise-linux-and-fedora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up fixing this for me was following Alexy Ten's link to https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#enterprise-linux-and-fedora.

After installing node as root the way described there, my php-fpm user had access to node.

I still wish I understood the difference between what I did at that link and just installing node as root via nvm, but hey, it works for now.

Thanks!